# How to print the result of a function in C?

Tags: c, function, printing

I'm currently working on a Tic Tac Toe game that will be interactive for a user. I think I have it all working, I just can't figure out how to get the displayBoard() function to print out the current state of the board so that the user knows which spaces are open and which spaces are not. How can I get the displayBoard() function to print to the screen?

My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void initializeBoard(char board[][3]);
void displayBoard(char board[][3]);
void makeMove(char board[][3], int player);

int main(void)
{
    char board[3][3];
    int row;
    int column;
    int move = 1;
    int player = 1;

    initializeBoard(board);


    while (move > 10)
    {
        displayBoard(board);
        makeMove(board, player);
        move++;
        if (move == 2 || move == 4 || move == 6 || move == 8)
        {
            player = 2;
        }//close of if
        else
        {
            player = 1;
        }//close of else
    }

}//close of main function

void initializeBoard(char board[][3])
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while (i < 4)
    {
        while (j < 4)
        {
            board[i][j] = ' ';
            j++;
        }//close of while loop

        j = 0;
        i++;
    }//close of while loop

}//close of initializeBoard

void displayBoard(char board[][3])
{
    printf("   1    2    3");
    printf("1 [%c] [%c] [%c]", board[1][1],board[1][2],board[1][3]);
    printf("2 [%c] [%c] [%c]", board[2][1],board[2][2],board[2][3]);
    printf("3 [%c] [%c] [%c]", board[3][1],board[3][2],board[3][3]);

}//close of displayBoard

void makeMove(char board[][3], int player)
{
    int row;
    int column;

    printf("Enter the row and column you'd like to fill:");
    scanf("%d %d", &row, &column);
    if (player == 1)
    {
        board[row][column] = 'X';
    }//close of if
    else
    {
        board[row][column] = 'O';
    }//close of else

}//close of makeMove
```

Comment: In C, arrays are zero-based.  Meaning a 3 element array has the elements [0], [1], and [2].  You may have other problems.

Comment: Not a single "\n" in the printfs looks wrong,

Comment: `while (i < 4)
    {
        while (j < 4)` --> `< 3`

Comment: Tip: With `scanf("%d %d", &row, &column);` check `scanf()` return value and the values of `row, column` before proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

you have written many things wrong, nor you have called any function to draw board in `main()`. Here, I have a better version of the game. You can see it and compare and make yours better. its pretty similar, its in C++ but if thats a problem, just change input and output lines. PS: i dont remember much of C 
goodluck.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

//to print digits on board and for checks

char num[10]={'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};

void gameBoard() //function to print board
{
    cout<<"     |     |     "<<endl;
    cout<<"  "<<num[1]<<"  |  "<<num[2]<<"  |  "<<num[3]<<"  "<<endl;
    cout<<"_____|_____|_____"<<endl;
    cout<<"     |     |     "<<endl;
    cout<<"  "<<num[4]<<"  |  "<<num[5]<<"  |  "<<num[6]<<"  "<<endl;
    cout<<"_____|_____|_____"<<endl;
    cout<<"     |     |     "<<endl;
    cout<<"  "<<num[7]<<"  |  "<<num[8]<<"  |  "<<num[9]<<"  "<<endl;
    cout<<"     |     |     "<<endl;

}
int win()   //function to check if a player wins or game is draw,
        // returns 1 if someone won, 0 if draw and -1 is game is still going on
{
    if(num[1]==num[2] && num[2]==num[3])
        return 1;
    else if(num[4]==num[5] && num[5]==num[6])
        return 1;
    else if(num[7]==num[8] && num[8]==num[9])
        return 1;
    else if(num[1]==num[4] && num[4]==num[7])
        return 1;
    else if(num[2]==num[5] && num[5]==num[8])
        return 1;
    else if(num[3]==num[6] && num[6]==num[9])
        return 1;
    else if(num[1]==num[5] && num[5]==num[9])
        return 1;
    else if(num[3]==num[5] && num[5]==num[7])
        return 1;
    else if(num[1]!='1' && num[2]!='2' && num[3]!='3' && num[4]!='4' && num[5]!='5' && num[6]!='6' && num[7]!='7' && num[8]!='8' && num[9]!='9')
        return 0;
    else
        return -1;
}
void input()   //function for player input and to assign both players signs.
{
    int choice,w,player=1;
    char sym;
    do{
    clrscr();
    gameBoard();
    player=(player%2)? 1:2;  //to check whos turn
    cout<<"\nPlayer "<<player<< " ,Enter Your Choice: ";
    cin>>choice;

    sym = (player == 1)? 'X' : 'O';  //assigns X to player 1 and O to player 2

    if(choice==1&&num[1]=='1')
    num[1]=sym;
    else if(choice==2&&num[2]=='2')
    num[2]=sym;
    else if(choice==3&&num[3]=='3')
    num[3]=sym;
    else if(choice==4&&num[4]=='4')
    num[4]=sym;
    else if(choice==5&&num[5]=='5')
    num[5]=sym;
    else if(choice==6&&num[6]=='6')
    num[6]=sym;
    else if(choice==7&&num[7]=='7')
    num[7]=sym;
    else if(choice==8&&num[8]=='8')
    num[8]=sym;
    else if(choice==9&&num[9]=='9')
    num[9]=sym;
    else
    {
        cout<<"\n\nWrong Move, Please enter again:";
        cin.ignore();
        player--;     //Ignores the input and let player choose again.
        getch();
    }
    w=win();
    player++;
    }while(w==-1);
    clrscr();
    gameBoard();

    if(w==1)
    cout<<"\n Player "<<--player<<" wins!!";
    else
    cout<<"\n Game Draw";
    getch();
}

int main()
{
    clrscr();
    input();    return 0;
}
```